# Javascript for loop strange behavior

Tags: javascript, for-loop, firefox

Hi am using javascript in mozilla firefox 53.0 and in for loop found this

case 1:  For sintaxis cause infinite loop and browser crash.

```
 for(var i=0;i<array.length;i+2)
        {
            console.log(array[i]);
            console.log(array[i+1]);
            console.log(array[i+2]);
        }
```

case 2:Normal loop behavior.

```
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i=i+2)
        {
            console.log(array[i]);
            console.log(array[i+1]);
            console.log(array[i+2]);
        }
```

Are both syntaxes correct? What can be producing the infinite cycle?
The array extracted from console.log (array)
Array [ "Dieguez Jorge Alberto", "Cel.: (02244) 453125", "jdieguez56@gmail.com" ]

Comment: the first one would cause a infinite loop as the last part you just have `i+2`, that does not update the variable `i`, so `i` is never going to be equal or higher than `array.length`

Comment: yes , for for(var i=0;i<array.length;i+2) i+2 has no sense , shut be marked as a sintax error haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop in JavaScript (and in Java, and in many other languages) has the following general syntax:

```
for (<loop variable; init>; <criteria check>; <change to loop variable>)
```

Please forgive me if this be not exact.  In your first loop:

```
for (var i=0; i < array.length; i+2)
```

your are telling JavaScript to compute `i+2` at the end of each loop iteration.  But you never assign this value back to the loop counter `i`.  Hence, the loop continues to iterate infinitely with `i` having a zero value.  However, in the following loop:

```
for (var i=0; i < array.length; i=i+2)
```

you are assigning `i+2` to `i`.  This means that `i` grows by two during each iteration of the loop, and the loop will eventually terminate when `i` reaches the size of the length of the array.

**Update:**

Based on your comment, it appears that you thought `i + 2` would increment and assign on the grounds that `i++` does so, without using an explicit equals sign.  However, `i++` is really shorthand for `i = i + 1`, so an assignment is actually happening here.  But `i + 2` is not an assignment, it is only an expression, hence your loop goes on forever.

Comment: I understand, use that syntax because I always use for (var i=0; i < array.length;i++)   and never had problems. When I write ++ the compilar trace back to i variable? There is any difference with i+2?

Comment: @user2402794 `i++` is shorthand for `i = i + 1`, so there actually is an assignment happening there, it's just not explicit.

Answer (score 0):

In the first loop you are not reassigning the variable `i`. `i + 2` is just a statement, never changing the value of `i`.

Due to this, the loop exit condition of `i < array.length` is never met and the loop never exits.

Answer (score 0):

in the first loop you are not reassign variable i ,  if you want to its must be like this

> i+=2 equal with i= i+2

if you only run i+2 its just statement and not change value of variabel i . so i would never increasing. maybe you can see the console  just print static but always loop . because i would never stop because of i never reach length of array. so, you have to make i break for the for-loop.